# Notifications and Alarm Manager not working

Tags: notifications, alarmmanager

Hi I've seen many questions about this issue and now here is mine here's my code in onclick, it never seems to work.

```
    if(v.getId() == In){

         Intent myIntent = new Intent(HelloAndroidActivity.this , TimeAlarm.class);     
           AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
           PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(HelloAndroidActivity.this, 0,         myIntent, 0);

           Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
               calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 3);
               calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
               calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

              alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,     calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000 , pi);
     }
```

And then here's the other part

```
public class TimeAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

     NotificationManager nm;

     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      String from = "Nithin";
      String message = "Crazy About Android...";
      PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(), 0);
      Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Crazy About Android...", System.currentTimeMillis());
      notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
      nm.notify(1, notif);
     }
    }
```

Also here's my manifest I hope that I put the receiver in the right place

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.CS340.smokingsurvey"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <receiver android:name=".TimeAlarm"></receiver>

    <activity

        android:name="com.CS340.smokingsurvey.HelloAndroidActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```